# TableToTable_conversion and FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion fail in script but succeed manually with Postgres

Tags: gis, arcgis, postgresql-9.5, arcpy

All,

I'm trying to copy some GIS data from an Oracle database into a Postgres database, both hosted in AWS.  I'm running a python script from an instantiated server where database connections to both databases have been established and work properly in all other testing conducted so far.  I'm specifically trying to use the arcpy functions TableToTable_conversion and FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion to transfer the data because other methods have proven too slow.  (Other methods being CopyFeatures/CopyRows, Append to empty shells, and SQL-based TRUNCATE/INSERT)  The two functions in use are the only ones I care about right now so I'm not looking for alternatives.  If I run the following command from a python shell, it works successfully:

```
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("TABLE1", r'C:\SDE_Connections\DB_CONNECT.sde', "TABLE1_COPY")
```

But if I run it from within the code, I get the following error:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\SDE_Connections\DB_CONNECT.sde\TABLE1_COPY
```

If I replace the database connection with an Oracle connection, it works from within the script too.  It's specifically when I try to use the postgres connection in the code that it fails.  The workspace is defined correctly beforehand and I'm using ArcGIS 10.5, Python 2.7.  Is anybody aware of a bug that prevents either of the aforementioned functions to fail inside a python script when postgres is the destination database for the output?  Again, if I copy and paste the code into a python shell, it succeeds.  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:  During the process of setting up these databases, I had been led to believe that they were snapshots and copies of a production database maintained outside the cloud.  Turns out that not everything was copied over.  Specifically, the production database had an arcpy environment configuration keyword that wasn't re-established.  An earlier section of the script being tested was setting that configuration keyword to a value that didn't exist, and thus the error that was observed.  Resetting the configuration keyword to "DEFAULTS" in the script resolved the issue.  Wish the error message hadn't been quite so generic though!